# Access denied connecting to database using PHP generated by MySQL WorkBench

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

I've seen a couple of similar posts, but none really help with my problem. I'm trying to connect to a database I created by using MySQL workbench. Under my user privileges in Workbench there's a GUI which allows you to enable all grants and permissions.

When I run the script `show grants for phpTester@localhost;` it shows:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'phpTester'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

So I know I have all permissions, and WorkBench also has a plug-in where you can copy your SQL to a clipboard and it will automatically extract your database settings so you can just copy and paste into your PHP script. So my script looks like this:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'forms1');
define('DB_USER', 'phpTester');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '12345');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_PORT', 2080);


$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD, DB_PORT);

if (!$link){
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if(!$db_selected){
  die('Not Working ' . DB_NAME . ':' . mysql_error());  
}
```

It fails with the error:

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'phpTester'@'localhost' (using password: YES) on line 10
Could not connect: Access denied for user 'phpTester'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

And When I use this line of PHP:

```
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER);
```

I get this error:

```
Not Working forms1:Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'forms1'.
```

But I do have a password set for this user, and I am using xampp for my localhost.

Comment: Make sure that you have a mysql user with name phpTester  and password 12345. Try to create a new user from the users section in your phpmyadmin. And try with those credentials. It is not the problem from php side. It is the problem related to mysql authentication and privilleges. Also notice mysql_* functions are depreciated so try to use mysqli.

Comment: I've had trouble with MySQl Workbench failing to flush the privileges after I've changed them. Just run 'FLUSH PRIVILEGES' from a query window.

Comment: Now i'm really starting to get confused. When i go to phpmyadmin and try to log in using phpTester, 12345. It says cannot log into mysql server. But When i go to mysql Workbench and login using phpTester, 12345 I can. I'm using xampp for my local host server. I made phpTester in workBench, so shouldn't that username be stored on my localhost for phpmyadmin to recognize?

Comment: So i was able to log into phpmyadmin by just using phpTester no password. (Which is weird because when i made it in workbench it has a password) this instance of phpTester has no created databases or anything. Then when i log out of phpmyadmin and log in using root. I don't even see a phpTester user.

Comment: can you query: `SELECT * FROM mysql.user \G;` you can get all the information that you need, permissions, username, password (empty pass) host, etc.

Be careful if you are going to post some information here. :)

Comment: I'm getting open permissions across the board.

Comment: In mysql workbench, does that user that the schema privilege for your database?

Comment: I didn't have schema privileges, but i just added them and i'm still getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was connecting to the wrong host, its a really simple fix, instead of connecting to 'localhost' you have to connect to the standard 127.0.0.1 loop back ip address, and port 3306. Then you enter your info like the user in your phpmyadmin and the password and you should be connected. Make sure that in your phpmyadmin that user has the privileges you need. And there you go, your workbench is connected to your phpmyadmin.